# ParseException on Dozer time

Tags: java, date-format, dozer

I have request object with

```
@Mapping("effectiveStartUtc")
@private String start_utc;
```

And i call following to convert the object into model. Here the mapper is `DozerBeanMapper`.

```
T model = mapper.map(object, type);
```

The model i map into is

```
@RestUpdatable
@Column(name="effective_start_utc")
private Timestamp effectiveStartUtc;
```

But I get exception

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-08-08T12:50:00"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at org.dozer.converters.DateConverter.convert(DateConverter.java:72) [dozer.jar:]
    ... 143 more
```

When i debug i found that i need to send date format with Z parameters. But How can i use a custom date adapter ? I found xml samples for dozer, but is there a way to use annotations ?

Comment: Where do you configure the `DateConverter`?

Comment: I dont, dozer users its default. I like to override that